# How to iterate a parameter from tibble to a function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, tibble

I would like ideias to iterate rows from `tibble` parameter into a `user function`.

I create a `loop for`, but I would like to use some functions of `Tidyverse`, like `purrr` or `dplyr`.

The data set with Keys of API is like this:

```
keys.bots <- tibble(bot = c('bot1', 'bot2', 'bot3', 'bot4', 'bot5'),
                    key = c('Key bot1','Key bot2','Key bot 3','Key bit 4','Key bot 5'))
```

Where each key should be iterated with some function with `purr` or `dplyr`, to iterate each key into the second parameter, `keys.bots[]`, in the function.

The function is:

```
fun.get_data_blip <- function(body, key, tzone){

  # Fetch Data from API
  request <- POST( url  = url
                   ,body = body
                   ,add_headers(.headers = c( 'Authorization' = key
                                              ,'Content-Type'  = 'application/json')))

  # Extracting Request Content
  content <- content(request, as = 'parsed')

  # Converting the List in Content to a Data Frame
  content$resource$items %>%
    toJSON() %>% 
    fromJSON() %>% 
    mutate( lastMessage.date_alt = ymd_hms(lastMessage$date, tz = tzone.sao_paulo)
           ,lastMessage.direction_alt = if_else(lastMessage$direction == 'sent', 'Bot', 'Usuário')
           ,'#' = row_number()) %>% 
    flatten(recursive = T) %>% 
    as_tibble()
```

The function in action:

```
tbl.chatbots <- fun.get_data_blip(body.threads, as.character(keys.bots[]), tzone.sao_paulo)
```

So during the iterate, the logic need to bind de result into `tbl.chatbots`, to increment the data of five bots one at time.

Comment: what is `fun.get_data_blip`

Comment: It would help if this question were a bit more reproducible and clear. For instance, as akrun commented, we don't know what your function is or does. Second, it would help to know what you expect `tbl.chatbots` to look like as output.

Comment: This is my function, I think it would be irrelevant to post the contents of it, since I'd just like to know how to iterate each `tbl.chatbots` line within the second parameter.

Comment: @r2evans, I agree. Above, I added the function

Comment: Are you looking for `rlang::exec` or `do.call`?